# PHP file_get_contents and cURL raise http error 500 internal server

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I am using a function inside a PHP class for reading images from array of URLs and writing them on local computer.

Something like below:

```
function ImageUpload($urls)
{
  $image_urls = explode(',', $urls);  
  foreach ($image_urls as $url)
  {
    $url = trim($url);
    $img_name = //something
    $source = file_get_contents($url);
    $handle = fopen($img_name, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $source);  
    fclose($handle);
  }
}
```

It successfully read and write 1 or 2 images but raise `500 Internal severs` for reading 2nd or 3rd image.
There is nothing important in Apache log file. Also i replace `file_get_contents` command with following cURL statements, but result is the same (it seems `cURL` reads one more image than `file_get_contents`).

```
$ch=curl_init();        
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,500);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
$source = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
unset($ch);
```

Also the problem is only for reading from http URLs, and if I have images on somewhere local, there is no problem for reading and writing them.

Comment: Doesn't the 500 come from the server you are trying to read from? If so, then the error information should be in the log of that server rather than yours.

Comment: I have not access to target server. if i read images one by one and echo on the screen , there will be no problem. but when i try to read all of them in a loop, the error generates.

Comment: I've deleted the answer from this question, since I see you have already posted the answer, and then deleted it. Please undelete the answer, since that's where this material belongs. Thanks!

Comment: (Mark for follow-up).

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changed to your code, hope that helps :)

```
$opts = array( 
        'http' => array( 
            'method'=>"GET", 
            'header'=>"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" 
        ) 
    );

$context = stream_context_create($opts); 
$image_urls = explode(',', $urls);  
foreach ($image_urls as $url) {
    $result = file_get_contents(trim($url),TRUE,$context);
    if($result === FALSE) {
        print "Error with this URL : " . $url . "<br />";
        continue; 
    }
    $handle = fopen($img_name, "a+");
    fwrite($handle, $result);  
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: can you give me some URL to make a try ?

Comment: No, it does not work... I can read files one by one , but problem is inside a loop.

Comment: @Amir : i have changed fopen($img_name, "w"); to fopen($img_name, "a+");

Comment: try again, i have fixed a bug :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any handler for reading in the loop , your `$handle = fopen($img_name, "w");` is just for writing , you also need `$handle = fopen($img_name, "r");` for reading ! because you can't read handle (`fread ()` ) for  `fopen($img_name, "w");`.

Additional answer :

Could you modify to (and see if it works):

```
.........
$img_name = //something
$context = stream_context_create($image_urls );
$source= file_get_contents(  $url ,false,$context);
.....
.....
```

Comment: also using `w` and `r` for reading BINARY data will corrupt your data in some OSs (famously Windows), for Windows support - and improved portability - add `b`, like `wb` and `rb`